# Google Spreadsheets: Counting number of matches between two rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

In a spreadsheet in Google Spreadsheets, I have multiple-choice answers I would like to grade.
One row (user 0) contains the answer key, and the other rows contain user answers.

```
User  Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4   Q5   Score
0     A    C    D    C    B
1     A    C    B    C    B    [need formula here]
2     B    A    C    D    B    [need formula here]
```

I'm trying to come up with a spreadsheet formula that would allow me to automatically calculate how many answers for a given user match up with the answer key, but I haven't had much luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

There's a function on Google Spreadsheets called [ARRAYFORMULA](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=71291). Here's how to use it in your case:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(EXACT($B$2:$F$2,B3:F3),1,0)))
```

This saves from the repetition of typing out:

```
=SUM(IF(EXACT($B$2,B3),1,0), IF(EXACT($C$2,C3),1,0), IF(EXACT($D$2,D3),1,0), etc...)
```

Assuming your spreadsheet was setup like this:

```
   A     B    C    D    E    F    G
1  User  Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4   Q5   Score
2  0     A    C    D    C    B    key
3  1     A    C    B    C    B    4
4  2     B    A    C    D    B    1
```